# Proof of a commutative group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G=\mathbb Q\setminus \{1/2\}$ with the following operation
$a*b=a+b+2ab$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb  Q$, belongs to $G$.

Prove that $(G,*)$ is a commutative group

Comment: What do you notice about the terms in the expression $a+b+2ab$? Hint: try substitution.

Comment: Isn't $G=\mathbf Q\setminus\{\color{red}-1/2\}$?

Comment: I edited this question, but since two of the answers, and perhaps what was clearly the "correct" question was $-1/2$, if anyone feels that it should be changed, that is fair.

Answer (score 2):

The map $x\mapsto 2x+1$ gives a bijection $f:\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{-1/2\}\to\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $f(a\ast b) = f(a)\cdot f(b)$.

So it is enough to show that $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}, \cdot)$ is a group, which should be more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

It is a group if you set $G=\mathbf Q\setminus\{-1/2\}$:

- Commutativity is clear since $a+b+2ab$ is a symmetric polynomial in $a$ and $b$.
- For associativity, one checks that
  \begin{align}(a*b)*c=(a+b+2ab)*c&=\bigl((a+b+2ab)+c+2(a+b+2ab)c\bigr)\\&=a+b+c+2(ab+bc+ca)+4abc,\end{align}
  which is, again, symmetrical in $a$, $b$, $c$. We would obtain the same final form computing $a*(b*c)$.
- Identity element: $a*0=0*a=a$.
- Inverses: Given $a$, we must find $b$ such that $a*b=a+b+2ab=a+b(1+2a)=0$. The solution is,  for all $a\neq -1/2$:
  $$b=-\frac a{1+2a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not a group.

Notice that $0$ is still the group identity: $0*a=0+a+2\cdot 0 \cdot a=a$.

For inverses: let $a \in G$. Then $a+b+2ab=0 \implies a+(b(1+2a))=0 \implies b= \frac{-a}{1+2a}$.

What is the inverse for $-\frac{1}{4}$?

Well, $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-a}{1+2a} \implies 1+2a=-2a \implies a=\frac{-1}{4}...$$

Looks like this element will not have an inverse in $G$.

Comment: $1/2$ is excluded from the domain of rational numbers.

Comment: that is exactly the problem

Comment: The inverse of $-\frac{1}{4}$ **would need to be**: $$-\frac{(-1/4)}{1-2/4}=\frac{1/4}{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ but this element is not in the group.